# How to know if htpdate has synchronized system clock?

Tags: linux, date, clock, synchronized, ntp

On my linux system, I use ntp to synchronize the system clock.
I also installed htpdate to synchronize it when ntp is not available.

To know if ntp has synchronized the clock, I call timedatectl that outputs :

> System clock synchronized: yes

But this "variable" is not changed when its htpdate that changes the system clock.

Is there a similar way to know if htpdate has set the system clock ?

Comment: why  not check with ntp?

Comment: Because sometimes ntp is not available due to the router (ntp port blocked)

Comment: If it's blocked hen ntp won't say that it's synchonized.

Comment: Yes but htpdate will get a date and synchronize the system clock.
How can I know that it synchronized it ? (I can see it in the logs but there is maybe a better way)

Comment: `ntpdate` is deprecated. `ntpq` is the query program.

Comment: Actually ntpstat is better

Comment: All I want to know is :
Is it possible to get the same info that timedatectl gives "System clock synchronized: yes" when its [htpdate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/htpdate) that synchronized the system clock

Answer (score 2):

htpdate doesn't set the kernel flag used by ntp and timedatectl (yet).

simple way of checking can be done like,

```
# htpdate example.com
Offset 0.125 seconds
```

or if your system is in sync, it will return

```
# htpdate example.com
No time correction needed
```

Update: in latest master (will be included in version htpdate 1.3.5) the "System clock synchronized: **yes**" will be set when used with "-x'

https://github.com/twekkel/htpdate